# Oracle 10g : insert statement with date and varchar2 values (ORA-00911 error)

Tags: oracle10g, ora-00911

I have created a table in Oracle 10g and trying to insert some rows into the table using insert statements. But I am repeatedly getting the following error:

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

And the insert statements that are giving the ORA-00911 error is as follows:

```
Insert into WinLossByDate (StatusDate, Status)
        Values (TO_DATE(‘2011-03-01’,‘yyyy-mm-dd’), ‘lose’);
```

N.B.My table definition is as follows

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -------------

 STATUSDATE                                NOT NULL DATE
 STATUS                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)
```

Can somebody help what is the error?

Comment: What application are you using?  Normally, you'd get this error because the tool you're using doesn't expect a semicolon.

Comment: Hi Justin, Yes as I removed the semi-colon at the end, the insert statement has started working successfully. Another change that Andy Skirrow has mentioned, I did that too i.e. replaced the curly quotes with the SQL editor quotes because I copied the quotes from Word. Btw, the editor I am using is Oracle 10g. Many thanks, Somnath!

Comment: @somnathchakrabarti - Oracle 10g is the database. The editor is the client tool you are using to access the database (Oracle SQL*PLUS, Toad, SQL Developer etc..). Just an FYI.

Comment: But I am using Oracle 10g XE which comes with a home web page and has its own SQL command tool with it. By Oracle 10g, I meant that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/e900.htm#sthref409) this appears to be a lexer error (e.g. oracle is having trouble breaking your statement down into tokens so it can parse it).

I've noticed that the quotes in your example are the pretty looking ones that have a left and right hand side (i.e. `’` and `‘` instead of `'` -- look closely to see the difference). Some word processors do this to make the text look nicer. Try manually retyping the quotes part of a statement into a plain text editor such as notepad or VIM.

Comment: Hi Andy, Yes u r right. I replaced the curly quotes (copied from Word) with the quotes of the SQL editor I am using, which is Oracle 10g in my case. I have also removed the semi-colons at the end and the two changes worked. Many thanks!